# Get all possible combinations of two integer lists

Tags: python

I have two lists of integers. I want to make all possible combinations of elements in list-1 with elements with list-2. For Example:

```
List-1    List-2
1         5
2         6
```

I need another list of all possible combinations like:

```
element-1    element-2
1            5
1            6
2            5
2            6
```

How to do that in python?

Comment: `[(x, y) for x in list1 for y in list2]` ?

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Please write that in answer section so that I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([1, 2], [5, 6]))
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try itertools :

```
list_1=[1,2]
list_2=[5,6]

import itertools
print([i for i in itertools.product(list_1,list_2)])
```

output:

```
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
```